# Latex template for an article from a popular (science) magazine

Tags: templates, article

I'm looking for a good latex template that is similar to those of popular (science) magazines. Think NewScientist, or Time magazine.

Its for writing an article concerning a technical subject (IPv6 networking) but to explain it to a regular, enthusiastic crowd. So no IEEE style, but plenty of pictures, smooth type setting and easy and fun to read. Like popular (science) magazines.

Comment: Hi and welcome, i think you are looking for something like `scrartcl`. But since i don't know, how »fun to read« article looks like, i can't go into detail.

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into two classes that might be interesting for you: papertex and newspaper. Please read the documentation, and PDF examples, for this classes and you'll probably be able to create magazine-like PDF.

Good luck in your quest!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.